# how to add directives dynamically while using ng-repeat in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have the following code on my homepage:-

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in list"  ng-controller="controller1"></li>
</ul>
```

now item has various properties like item.type, item.title, item.content, item.webService...

if the item.content is null then the item.webService is called to get the content and each item.type has its own template of rendering

so i thought of writing directives for each item.type which takes care of manipulating DOM on its own from the *template:* and *link* properties

**in link:** i call the webservice get the content

**in template:** i specify the template for the particular item.type...

```
directive("directive1", function ($http) {
try {
    return {
        restrict: "E",

        transclude: true,
        scope: {


            sWebServicePath: "="
        },

        template: template1,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var request = {};

            $http({ method: "POST", url: scope.sWebServicePath, data: request }).
            success(function (data, status) {
                scope.response = data;
            }).
            error(function (data, status) {
                alert("Service Call Error");
            })
        }
    }
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
});
```

so, 
type1 is handled by directive1
type2 by directive2 and so on..

now  i want controller1 to have the above specified mapping say in

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in list"  ng-controller="controller1"></li>
</ul>
```

when the **controller1** encounters **item.type=1** then it should call **directive1** which in turn would call the **item.webservice** get the data and would include the **template1** with the response from webservice

what is the ideal way to achieve the mentioned functionality? please do comment if there is an alternative thank you!

Comment: why not make the call when initial data is loaded? Loop through it and check content right away before passing it to scope

Comment: in the above case item.location is an attribute which decides if the item appears on left or right... so the list that you see above is actually leftList and rightList both in separate sections of page...i iterate over these lists and render the content..lemme know if you think i should change the approach